# unable load csv data in tensorflow2 using csvDataset

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning

```
a = [[i for i in [1]*5] for j in range(5)]
a = pd.DataFrame(a)
a.head()
type(a.iloc[0,0])
a.to_csv('float.csv',index = False,header = False,float_format = 'int32')
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
dataset = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset("f.csv", 
    [tf.int32,tf.int32,tf.int32,tf.int32,tf.int32],
        header=False,field_delim=' ')
for element in dataset:
    print(element)
```

> error: field 0 in record is not a valid int 32

I can't go any simpler than this I am just not able to get this right. This is the colab link to what I have done: [colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1npqU3fscpAQWeKiv9usHRqPwObSek9uL#scrollTo=5QYuheAuy4mc)

Comment: Could you show the entire Traceback? The error is occurring on a particular statement.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1npqU3fscpAQWeKiv9usHRqPwObSek9uL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your delimitator is not correct.
Change this line

```
dataset = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset("float.csv", [tf.int32,tf.int32,tf.int32,tf.int64,tf.int64],header=False,field_delim=' ') # Only parse last three columns
```

to this

```
dataset = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset("float.csv", [tf.int32,tf.int32,tf.int32,tf.int64,tf.int64],header=False,field_delim=',') # Only parse last three columns
```

and your issue should be solved